# Why my website work on: http://example.com but on www.example.com not working?

Tags: apache-2.2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/proj/proj/static/

        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/proj
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/proj/proj/index.wsgi


        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Why my website work on:

http://example.com but on www.example.com not working?

Comment: In what way is it not working ? Are there any relevant messages in your logs and in the browser?

Comment: @Iain: If I run www.example.com in browser I have: `It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.` From `http://example.com` work fine.

Comment: Well, either you are reaching the wrong server, or your virtual host config is messed up somehow.

Comment: Check your DNS to ensure that www.example.com and example.com point to the same IP address.

Comment: FYI. Also cross-posted on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/333526/why-my-website-work-on-http-example-com-but-on-www-example-com-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com are not the same machine. Check your DNS and ensure that [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com resolve to the same IP address.

Take appropriate action.